# Help with EntityQuery working Silverlight C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework

I have the following code:

```
var data = (sender as Button).DataContext as Web.Booking;

EntityQuery<Web.Ticket> ticketQuery =
    from t in _ticketContext.GetTicketsQuery()
    where t.ticketId == data.ticketId
    select t;

LoadOperation<Web.Ticket> loadTicket = this._ticketContext.Load(ticketQuery);
loadTicket.Completed += (s, args) => { MessageBox.Show("Loaded Tickets!"); };

ticketDomainDataSource.DataContext = loadTicket.AllEntities;

var ticketData = ticketDomainDataSource.DataContext as Web.Ticket;
string ticketName = ticketData.ticketName;
```

The main code that I'm having trouble with is the:

```
var ticketData = ticketDomainDataSource.DataContext as Web.Ticket;
    string ticketName = ticketData.ticketName;
```

It returns an error:

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

Can anyone help me out on what I'm doing wrong here, I can't figure out what's null and how I can return proper data.

Thanks

Comment: Obviously `ticketData` is null. Maybe `ticketDomainDataSource.DataContext` cannot be cast to `Web.Ticket`. Check around that area.

Comment: I have checked for the past 30 mins, can't understand why it isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is likely that DataContext cannot be cast to Web.Ticket.   If you look at the documentation for C# -- `as` returns a null on a conversion failure.  See - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

If you change your line of code to

```
var ticketData = (Web.Ticket) ticketDomainDataSource.DataContext;
```

you should get a better cast error.

Comment: Can not convert DomainContext to Web.Show